# Docker Redis Connection refused

Tags: php, docker, redis, dockerfile

I'm trying to access Redis server through the code and it's not connecting. But if i bash to the redis container i can access the redis-cli.

docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile_nginx
   ports:
    - "9000:80"
   environment:
    - NGINX_SERVERNAME=xxx.dev *.xxx.dev
   command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_SERVERNAME' < /var/www/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
                          && dos2unix /var/www/provision/init_storage.sh && sh /var/www/provision/init_storage.sh
                          && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
   volumes:
     - .:/var/www
   links:
     - php
   networks:
     frontend

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_php-fpm
    command: /bin/bash -c "composer install
              && php-fpm"
    volumes:
          - .:/var/www
    environment:
          - APP_ENV=local
          - APP_DEBUG=true
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    links:
         - redis
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxx
    networks:
      - backend
  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile_redis

```
FROM redis:latest
```

When i try to connect to the redis server using this code

```
$redis = new \Redis();
    try {
        $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage())  ;
        die;
    }
```

It gives this warning

```
Warning: Redis::connect(): connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Does anyone know how to connect Redis container to PHP container ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Your Problem

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) creates separated docker container for different services. Each container are, logically speaking, like different separated computer servers that only connected with each other through docker network.

Consider each boxes in this diagram as an individual computer, then this is practically what you have:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                       your machine                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
                               |                    
        +------ (virtual network by docker) -------+
        |                      |                   |
+-----------------+ +-------------------+ +----------------+
| "php" container | | "redis" container | | "db" container |
+-----------------+ +-------------------+ +----------------+
```

Your PHP container doesn't see any redis in "localhost" because there is no redis in it. Just like it would't see any MySQL in "localhost". Your redis is running in the "redis" container. Your MySQL is running in your "db" container.

The things that confuses you is the port binding directives (i.e. `ports` in this definition):

```
redis:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile_redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

The port `6379` of the "redis" container is binded to your computer, but **to your computer ONLY**. Other container doesn't have the same access to the port bindings. So even your computer can connect it with '127.0.0.1:6379', the `php` container cannot do the same.

### Solution

As described in [Networking in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), each docker compose container can access other container by using the service name as hostname. For example, your programming running by service `php` can access your MySQL service with the hostname `db`.

So you should connect redis with its hostname `redis`

```
$redis = new \Redis();
try {
    $redis->connect('redis', 6379);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage())  ;
    die;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've added networks.

redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_redis
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

Comment: great ascii diagram and explanation!

Comment: Good explanation, I had similar problem for python program. I started the docker image with outbound port and network as host to make it accessible from python client program.

Answer (score 15):

just remove the redis port and change the redis hostname to `redis` in your Laravel project .env file.

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
#REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a static-ip for your network use below instead of localhost

```
$redis->connect('<static-ip>', 6379);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this config.

host' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

'port' => 6379,

Answer (score 0):

Just write your container name into host in your `.env` file. And run

```
artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating and starting redis server in docker. 
Use these setting in laravel .env

SESSION_DRIVER=redis 
CACHE_DRIVER=redis 
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local 
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis

REDIS_HOST=redis 
REDIS_PASSWORD=null 
REDIS_PORT=6379 
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

if you are working with redis laravel cache::

append this at the end 
 config/database.php

redis => [ ../

```
    'session' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
    ],
```

and also you need to add phpredis or predis

Answer (score 0):

if your redis container is name redis, change your .env to:

```js
REDIS_HOST=redis
```

Answer (score -2):

### docker-compose.yml Config

```
    lnmp-redis:
    image: yahuiwong/lnmp:redis3.2.9
    hostname: lnmp-redis-v3
    ports:
        - "63789:63789"
```

### Example

```
    $redis = new \Redis();
var_dump($redis);
try {
    $redis->connect('lnmp-redis-v3', 63789);
    var_dump($redis->keys("*"));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage())  ;
}
```