# Cannot connect to redis from different docker container

Tags: docker, redis, dockerhub

currently I have one personal docker image uploaded to DockerHub, I am making the changes to connect this application to redis (that is running in another docker container as well)

Now, I have the next message from my app when it tries to connect to redis:

```
 Error saving to redis: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: connect: connection refused
```

I understand that they're not in the same network, so my app is pointing to 127.0.0.1:6379 that is not executing anything, so, I am looking for the best way to connect those containers in some way that don't make my app depending of the IP where redis is hosted, from my local machine I can use redis, but not from another docker container. Briefly, what I did was:

```
docker run --name redis_server -p 6379:6379 -d redis
sudo docker run -d --restart=always -p 10000:10000 --link redis_server:redis --name my_app repo/my_app
```

So, I am looking for solutions on how to make 127.0.0.1:6379 accessible for my_app. I don't use docker-compose by the way

Comment: I believe running both containers with "--network=host" is your easiest solution.

Comment: @Neekoy thank you very much, it works!! what security concerns should I consider with "--network=host" do that makes me vulnerable or anything?

Comment: Well if you don't have a firewall this way you will expose the services on those ports to the outside world on your IP. A safer solution might be to define a network beforehand, and then place both containers on it. I'll write an answer in a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Redis Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360356/docker-redis-connection-refused)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to run Docker with "--network=host" which binds the containers to the host network. This is a perfectly fine solution for testing, however it will expose the ports and services respectively to the internet (if you don't have a firewall), which may or may not be secure.

Another way of doing this would be to define a network in the following way:

```
docker network create -d bridge my-net
```

And then to run your containers on that same network by running the `docker run` command with `--network=my-net`. This way you can reference each container by its name. For example in your case you can `ping my_app` from the Redis container and vice-versa.