# Can not access nextjs docker example image

Tags: docker, next.js

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to get this nextjs example to work: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env

I have installed Docker with this guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Then I executed the following

```
npx create-next-app --example with-docker-multi-env nextjs-docker-multi-env
make build-development
make start-development
```

Now when I try to access http://localhost:3001 in Firefox the website does not show up ("The connection was reset").

The output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
1ffae309639e   with-docker-multi-env-development   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp, :::3001->3000/tcp   development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1
```

Output of the docker image:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                             
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  Created                                                                          0.0s 
Attaching to development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1
development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  |    ▲ Next.js 14.0.3
development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  |    - Local:        http://localhost:3000
development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  |    - Network:      http://127.0.0.1:3000
development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  | 
development-with-docker-multi-env-development-1  |  ✓ Ready in 55ms
```

Other docker images like https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres work for me without problems.

Are there additional steps I have to take to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. For all people having the same problem:

You have to change following line inside the `Dockerfile`:

```js
ENV HOSTNAME localhost
```

to

```js
ENV HOSTNAME 0.0.0.0
```

For some reason they have this exact line in [a different `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile).

Comment: yes and the explanation for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77761354/6141587). i faced a similar problem with redis too & [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361204/6141587) for that as well.