# Next JS Docker multistage can't be accessed on localhost

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have followed how to dockerized Next JS multi build for Next JS 14 and even cloned the repo to verify I haven't missed any config but I can't access my build on my browser. When I type docker ps, It shows on the terminal with port 3000.
And I can also verify that it is running via docker desktop ui and I can also go inside the container via docker exec -it container_id sh
However, when I access it via http://localhost:3000, It shows unable to connect
[image]

Here is the instruction I followed on my project: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env

To verify that it's not about wsl2 issue, I have a containerized laravel project and I can access it well.

Here is my dockerfile

```
# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
# COPY .env.development.sample .env.production
RUN yarn build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# FROM https://dev.to/francescoxx/wtfnextjs-app-deployed-with-docker-4h3m
# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: 'lux-fe-tstw'
    image: luxfetstw
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/development/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Did I missed anything? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: A frequent symptom of this is your application running some sort of dev server that's only listening on 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0.  How does your `server.js` script set up its network listener?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, Thank you for responding. the server.js is automatically created by next.js on my case, I've checked inside the container via docker exec and it's present there. Some part of server.js
const path = require('path')

const dir = path.join(__dirname)

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
process.chdir(__dirname)

if (!process.env.NEXT_MANUAL_SIG_HANDLE) {
  process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.exit(0))
  process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(0))
}

const currentPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || '0.0.0.0'

Comment: ...then `ENV HOSTNAME localhost` in the Dockerfile causes it, and you should just delete that line.

Comment: Damnnn, it worked! Could you please explain it for me for a bit? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular setup, it is enough to remove the `ENV HOSTNAME localhost` line from your Dockerfile.

A container process runs in an isolated network environment.  If the process is configured to only listen on 127.0.0.1 or `localhost`, that is a `localhost` that's private to the container, and it won't generally accept connections from other containers or the host system.  Also see for example [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).  You generally need to set a container process to listen on 0.0.0.0, a special value that means "all interfaces".

In comments you suggest code that looks like:

```js
const currentPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || '0.0.0.0'
app.listen(currentPort, hostname)
```

Note here that, if you set neither environment variable, you'll get a very reasonable default of listening on 0.0.0.0:3000.  That's probably what you want running in Docker, and so deleting both `ENV` settings at the end of the file will fix the issue.  The important one is deleting the `HOSTNAME` setting, so that you use the `0.0.0.0` default in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. Now I really understand better why I can't access it. Thank you again, I'm just a beginner on docker and this really helps :D

Comment: i use `ENV HOSTNAME 0.0.0.0` in my dockerfiles now with next.js as recommended in the official examples.